# React Component Giving me unpredictable results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am a novice in React.js an am making my first component. What this component does is it calculates a future date based on the selected date and the number of days to be added.
The User chooses a date from the first date selector and then enters the number of days to be added to the selected date. Then the second date selector automatically shows the final date. 
So as you change the first date or the number of days the final date selector should reflect that.

I tried a lot but I am getting very unpredictable results and it looks very difficult for me to debug

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class DateCalc extends Component {

DateCalcHandler (event) {
    console.log("DateCalc: "+this.state.numberOfDays);
    let selectedDate = new Date(this.refs.date.value);
    console.log("Current Date: "+selectedDate);
    let futureDate = new Date(selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate()+this.state.numberOfDays));
    futureDate = futureDate.getFullYear() + '-' + 
                (("0" + (futureDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)) + '-' + 
                ("0" + futureDate.getDate()).slice(-2);

    console.log(futureDate);
    this.setState({newDate: futureDate});
}; 

NumberOfDaysChangeHandler (event) {
    console.log("NumberChange: "+this.refs.numberOfDays.value);
    this.setState({numberOfDays: this.refs.numberOfDays.value});
}


constructor(){
    super();
    this.DateCalcHandler = this.DateCalcHandler.bind(this);
    this.NumberOfDaysChangeHandler = this.NumberOfDaysChangeHandler.bind(this);
    let dt = new Date();

    let today = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + 
                (("0" + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)) + '-' + 
                ("0" + dt.getDate()).slice(-2);


    this.state = {
        date: today,
        newDate: '',
        numberOfDays: 0
    };
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <input type="date" ref="date" name="date" onChange ={this.DateCalcHandler }/>
            <input type="number" 
                ref="numberOfDays" name="numberOfDays" 
                value = { this.state.numberOfDays } 
                onChange = { this.NumberOfDaysChangeHandler } 
                placeholder="Enter Number Of Days..."/>
            <input type="date" ref="newDate" name="newDate" value = { this.state.newDate }/>
        </div>  
    )

}
```

}

export default DateCalc;

If I have written any code which is not a best practice feel free to correct me.

Comment: Use something like moment (https://momentjs.com/) to work with dates and time.

Comment: @ShanakaRusith Its actually not the problem of the way I calculate the date, rather something to do with the state updating. I tried debugging by using a hard coded numberOfDays and it works properly

Comment: Should not you be setting the `newDate` also in the `NumberOfDaysChangeHandler` ?

Comment: @ShanakaRusith I dont get you. Can you explain again?Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your `NumberOfDaysChangeHandler` you should also be changing `numberOfDays` value and setting your state. I'm suggesting to move your calculation to another method and trigger it when number of days and date is changing.

Comment: But in my NumberOfDaysChangeHandler , I am changing my numberOfDays to the <input> value and setting the state. Or am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you're setting this value and it's 100% correct, but your calculations of date will not be triggered after this change unless you will do it manually. You're displaying `newDate` and you should calculate new date if one of this values changes, so you need to do that in both of the handlers.

Comment: How can I do that ? I am not aware of it.Thanks!

Comment: I am facing one more problem regarding states.After updating a particular state and using the state, I'm always getting the previous state and not the updated state.What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you deploy your code to jsfiddle or something similar ? It would be easier if I can saw all your code.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/150451/  It is working fine now, but can you review it and comment on whether the code follows best practices and whether it can be improved?Thanks!